# Azure event hub consumer groups vs Kafka consumer groups via Spring cloud stream kafka binder

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I was able to use spring cloud stream kafka binder and have it connected to Azure event hubs . My confusion is regarding consumers groups . I have given the property `spring.cloud.bindings.<channelname>.group` in the consumer application.yml . Does it mean that this group is different from a consumer group with the same name which i create on eventhub . Also how about offset commits . Does it behave the same way as in Kafka . I read some mechanism called checkpointing in eventhub . Since i am using Kafka binders , do i not get to leverage checkpointing for error handling . Does the default Kafka offset commit strategy suffice . I am finding a bit hard to have a big picture based on docs . Would appreciate if this can be explained in simple terms

Comment: It looks like event hub is compatible with Kafka API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview. I would assume that the consumer group concept is mapped properly.

Comment: HI Soby , Yes the concept matches ( i think although not quite sure ) , Am not getting when one should go with manually creating the consumer groups manually in eventhub vs going with normal kafka consumer groups ( which does not need to be created manually although it can be done )

Comment: I am exactly looking for the same. Did you get any answer?

Comment: @chaosguru not yet